# Stop iterating and return true when a match is found between two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexeddb, pouchdb

I have two datasets, one in indexedDB and one in PouchDB (yes I know PouchDB is an implementation of indexedDB).

The one in indexedDB is a list of rooms, stored in indexedDB via a previous page, and displayed on the current page.

The one in PouchDB is the log of room usage recorded by a room auditor. I want to iterate through the first list, and check if each item appears in the list of audited rooms. If it does appear, I want to set a flag to indicate that.

Here's my Javascript. (I have run this in a browser and it does return true at some point in the process, because the console log output shows that, but the flag doesn't get set against the list item.)

I am wondering if it continues to loop through the audit records and overwrites the "true" value?

this is the function that queries indexedDB and calls the function that queries PouchDB:

```
function getRoomsInRoute() {
    var routeNumber = $.jStorage.get('currentRoute', '');
    var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB || window.shimIndexedDB;

    openRequest = window.indexedDB.open("rooms", 1);
    openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function() {
        var db = openRequest.result;
        var itemStore = db.createObjectStore("rooms", {keyPath: "room_id"});
        var index = itemStore.createIndex("rooms", ["route_number"]);
    };

    openRequest.onerror = function(event) {
        console.error(event);
    };

    openRequest.onsuccess = function (event) {
        var db = openRequest.result;
        db.onerror = function(event) {
            // Generic error handler for all errors targeted at this database's requests
            console.error(event.target);
            console.log("Database error: " + event.target.error.name || event.target.error || event.target.errorCode);
        };
        var transaction = db.transaction(['rooms'], "readwrite");
        var itemStore = transaction.objectStore("rooms");
        var index = itemStore.index("rooms", ["route_number"]);
        console.log('DB opened');
        var intRouteNumber = parseInt(routeNumber);
        //var range = IDBKeyRange.only(intRouteNumber);

        itemStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
            var cursor = event.target.result;
            if(cursor) {
                var audited;
                if(cursor.value.route_number == routeNumber) {
                    if (checkIfAudited(cursor.value.room_seq)) {
                        var audited = ' <span class="checked"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>';
                    } else {
                        var audited = "";
                    }
                    $('#mylist').append("<li id="+ cursor.value.room_id +" rel="+ cursor.value.room_seq +"> " + '<small>'+ cursor.value.room_seq + '.&nbsp;</small><a href="/static?action=edit&amp;room_id='+ cursor.value.room_id +'&amp;route_number='+ cursor.value.route_number +'&amp;sequence='+ cursor.value.room_seq +'&amp;roomname='+ cursor.value.room_name +'&amp;capacity='+ cursor.value.room_capacity +'">' + cursor.value.room_name + '</a>'+audited+'</li> ');
                }

                cursor.continue();
            } else {
                console.log('Entries all displayed.');
                if(!($.jStorage.get('reverseroute', ''))) {
                    reverseroute = 'asc';

                } else {
                    reverseroute = $.jStorage.get('reverseroute', '');
                }
                appendHref(reverseroute);
            }
        };

        // Close the db when the transaction is done
        transaction.oncomplete = function() {
            db.close();
        };
    };
}
```

and this is the function that queries PouchDB to see if it has been audited:

```
function checkIfAudited(roomseq) {
    var today = new Date();
    if(is_BST(today) == true) {
        var currentHour = today.getHours()+1;
    } else {
        var currentHour = today.getHours();
    }
    var currentDay = today.getDate();
    var currentMonth = today.getMonth();

    options = {},
    that = this,
    pdb = new PouchDB('pouchroomusage');
    options.include_docs = true;
    var pouchOpts = {
      skipSetup: true
    };
    var opts = {live: true};

    pdb.allDocs(options, function (error, response) {
        response.rows.some(function(row){
            var auditTime = new Date(row.doc.timestamp);
            var auditHour = auditTime.getUTCHours();
            var auditDay = auditTime.getDate();
            var auditMonth = auditTime.getMonth();
            if(row.doc.sequence == roomseq && currentHour == auditHour && currentDay == auditDay && currentMonth == auditMonth) {
                var isAudited = true;   
                console.log('RoomSeq: ' + roomseq + '; auditHour: ' + auditHour + '; currentHour: ' + currentHour + '; auditDay: ' + auditDay); 
                console.log('currentDay: ' + currentDay + '; auditMonth: ' + auditMonth + '; currentMonth: ' + currentMonth + '; isAudited: ' + isAudited);
            } else {
                var isAudited = false;
                console.log('No matches');
            }
            return isAudited;
        });
    });
}
```

I have read a number of other questions and answers about comparing two arrays.

I don't know how to use a `for` loop with `pdb.allDocs` though :(

Here is the output from `console.log`:

> 49 No matches
>
> RoomSeq: 1; auditHour: 14; currentHour: 14; auditDay: 16
>   currentDay: 16; auditMonth: 0; currentMonth: 0; isAudited: true
>
> 2300 No matches

**So how do I get the second function to stop and return true when it hits a matching record in PouchDB?**

Comment: or is it because I am returning the variable `isAudited` and the calling function doesn't know what to do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up with after much tweaking.

Now it adds `<span class="checked"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>` more than once per `<li>` but at least it adds to every `<li>`.

So I did a little hack to the CSS to only display one `span.checked`:

```
.checked {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #006338;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 2px 3px;
}

/* only display the first instance of checked */
li > span.checked ~ .checked {
    display: none;
}
```

(I also found and fixed another error in my script, where I wasn't setting `route_number` or `room_id`.)

```
function getRoomsInRoute() {
    var routeNumber = $.jStorage.get('currentRoute', '');
    var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB || window.shimIndexedDB;

    openRequest = window.indexedDB.open("rooms", 1);
    openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function() {
        var db = openRequest.result;
        var itemStore = db.createObjectStore("rooms", {keyPath: "room_id"});
        var index = itemStore.createIndex("rooms", ["route_number"]);
    };

    openRequest.onerror = function(event) {
        console.error(event);
    };

    openRequest.onsuccess = function (event) {
        var db = openRequest.result;
        db.onerror = function(event) {
            // Generic error handler for all errors targeted at this database's requests
            console.error(event.target);
            console.log("Database error: " + event.target.error.name || event.target.error || event.target.errorCode);
        };
        var transaction = db.transaction(['rooms'], "readwrite");
        var itemStore = transaction.objectStore("rooms");
        var index = itemStore.index("rooms", ["route_number"]);
        console.log('DB opened');
        var intRouteNumber = parseInt(routeNumber);
        //var range = IDBKeyRange.only(intRouteNumber);

        itemStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
            var cursor = event.target.result;
            var audited = "";
            if(cursor) {
              if(cursor.value.route_number == routeNumber) {

                $('#mylist').append("<li id="+ cursor.value.room_id +" rel="+ cursor.value.room_seq +"> " + '<small>'+ cursor.value.room_seq + '.&nbsp;</small><a href="/static?action=edit&amp;room_id='+ cursor.value.room_id +'&amp;route_number='+ cursor.value.route_number +'&amp;sequence='+ cursor.value.room_seq +'&amp;roomname='+ cursor.value.room_name +'&amp;capacity='+ cursor.value.room_capacity +'">' + cursor.value.room_name + '</a></li> ');


              }

              cursor.continue();

            } else {
                console.log('Entries all displayed.');
                if(!($.jStorage.get('reverseroute', ''))) {
                    reverseroute = 'asc';
                } else {
                    reverseroute = $.jStorage.get('reverseroute', '');
                }
                appendHref(reverseroute);

                asyncCallToPouchDb();
            }
        };


        // Close the db when the transaction is done
        transaction.oncomplete = function() {
            db.close();
        };
    };
}


function asyncCallToPouchDb() { 
    $('#mylist li').each(function(){
        var audited = "";
        var room_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var thisLi = $(this);
        audited = callPouchDb(room_id, thisLi);

    });
}


function callPouchDb(room_id, thisLi) {
    options = {},
    pdb = new PouchDB('pouchroomusage');
    options.include_docs = true;
    var audited = "";
    //return new Promise(resolve => {
         pdb.allDocs(options, function (error, response) {
            result = response.rows;
            for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { 
                if (checkIfAudited(result[i], room_id)) {
                    audited = ' <span class="checked"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>';
                } 
                thisLi.append(audited);
            } 
            //thisLi.append(audited);
            /*end pdb.allDocs*/
        }).then(function (result) {

          // handle result
          console.log(result);

        }).catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err);
        });

    // });

}

function checkIfAudited(row, room_id) {

    var today = new Date();
    if(is_BST(today) == true) {
        var currentHour = today.getHours()+1;
    } else {
        var currentHour = today.getHours();
    }
    var currentDay = today.getDate();
    var currentMonth = today.getMonth();
    var currentYear = today.getYear();

    var isAudited = false;    ///// <---- define isAudited outside of db iteration scope

      var auditTime = new Date(row.doc.timestamp);
      var auditHour = auditTime.getUTCHours();
      var auditDay = auditTime.getDate();
      var auditMonth = auditTime.getMonth();
      var auditYear = auditTime.getYear();
      if(row.doc.room_id == room_id && currentHour == auditHour && currentDay == auditDay && currentMonth == auditMonth && currentYear == auditYear) {
        isAudited = true;   
        // debug 
   //     console.log('RoomSeq: ' + roomseq + '; auditHour: ' + auditHour + '; currentHour: ' + currentHour + '; auditDay: ' + auditDay); 
   //     console.log('currentDay: ' + currentDay + '; auditMonth: ' + auditMonth + '; currentMonth: ' + currentMonth + '; isAudited: ' + isAudited);
      } else {
         console.log('No matches');
      };

    return isAudited 
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the **pouchdb method alldocs is asynchronous**.
But you test audition in a synchronous way. Therefore whatever the pdb.alldocs callback function returns will be returned after the `checkIfAudited` is already returned. Therefore `checkIfAudited` always returns `undefined`.

In my opinion, you should create the pouchdb instance only once in `temStore.openCursor().onsuccess`. Then you need to properly return audit state in `checkIfAudited` function.

For example, you could do something like the following:

```
itemStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {

  var cursor = event.target.result;

  if (cursor) {

    if (cursor.value.route_number == routeNumber) {

      var audited;
      options = {},
      pdb = new PouchDB('pouchroomusage');
      options.include_docs = true;

      pdb.allDocs(options, function (error, allDocsResponse) {

        if (checkIfAudited(allDocsResponse, cursor.value.room_seq)) audited = ' <span class="checked"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>'

        else audited = "";

        $('#mylist').append("<li id="+ cursor.value.room_id +" rel="+ cursor.value.room_seq +"> " + '<small>'+ cursor.value.room_seq + '.&nbsp;</small><a href="/static?action=edit&amp;room_id='+ cursor.value.room_id +'&amp;route_number='+ cursor.value.route_number +'&amp;sequence='+ cursor.value.room_seq +'&amp;roomname='+ cursor.value.room_name +'&amp;capacity='+ cursor.value.room_capacity +'">' + cursor.value.room_name + '</a>'+audited+'</li> ');

      });

    };

    cursor.continue();

  } else {

    console.log('Entries all displayed.');

    if(!($.jStorage.get('reverseroute', ''))) reverseroute = 'asc'

    else reverseroute = $.jStorage.get('reverseroute', '');

    appendHref(reverseroute);

  };


};
```

And for checkIfAudited:

```
function checkIfAudited(allDocs, roomseq) {


    var today = new Date();
    if(is_BST(today) == true) {
        var currentHour = today.getHours()+1;
    } else {
        var currentHour = today.getHours();
    }
    var currentDay = today.getDate();
    var currentMonth = today.getMonth();

    for (i=0; i<allDocs.rows.length; i++) {
      var row = allDocs.rows[i];

      var auditTime = new Date(row.doc.timestamp);
      var auditHour = auditTime.getUTCHours();
      var auditDay = auditTime.getDate();
      var auditMonth = auditTime.getMonth();
      if(row.doc.sequence == roomseq && currentHour == auditHour && currentDay == auditDay && currentMonth == auditMonth) {
        console.log('RoomSeq: ' + roomseq + '; auditHour: ' + auditHour + '; currentHour: ' + currentHour + '; auditDay: ' + auditDay); 
        console.log('currentDay: ' + currentDay + '; auditMonth: ' + auditMonth + '; currentMonth: ' + currentMonth + '; isAudited: ' + isAudited);
        return true;    ///// <---- return that it is audited
      } else {
        console.log('No matches');
      };

    });

    return false    ///// <---- return false if no iteration has matched
}
```

Comment: That's a very elegant solution, but I am getting an error: `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'continue' on 'IDBCursor': The transaction has finished.` I wonder if it is because you have nested the IDB cursor inside pdb.allDocs ?

Comment: I don't know exactly where this error comes from. But, you can putting the pouchdb instance creation and pdb.allDocs inside the `if(cursor)` or even inside `if(cursor.value.route_number == routeNumber)`. Then you should not affect any other part of your code, to test audition, apart from the DOM element creation, and it probably shouldn't matter that that's done asynchronously.

Comment: I think that's it - just needed to put `$('#mylist').append("...` outside the `pdb.allDocs` function

Comment: If you take out `$('#mylist')` from `pdb.allDocs` callback, it won't work again. Since the callback of `pdb.allDocs` is asynchronous, you would append the dom element showing `audited` value before `audited` value is set.

Comment: yay, that worked. For some reason it is now not sorting the list properly (another separate function) but that is probably due to the point in the process when I call the sort function. It is also doing a weird thing of putting some rooms in the list more than once, but I think that is a separate issue.

Comment: I shall mark your answer as the accepted one but wonder if you could edit it, as it doesn't work as it stands, only after I did the things you suggested in the comments. Thank you ver y much indeed for your help.

Comment: I've edited my answer accordingly. I'd still suggest that you fragment your code much more, into separate functions for different functionalities. I think it would make it clearer and easier to debug/improve.

Comment: yes, and I am now finding that even the revised version marks the first item as audited and then for some reason, `roomseq` remains set at 1 throughout -- so I need to use a promise instead -- working on that now

Answer (score 1):

First, I wouldn't get too fancy with exploiting the short-circuiting behavior of `Array.prototype.some`. Use the native functionality available to you. indexedDB provides a built in way to stop advancing a cursor, or load only a limited number of objects from a store.

Second, you probably want to avoid loading all objects from a store when you are only interested a in a few of those objects. Use a cursor to walk the store. Since you appear to want to stop iterating when meeting some condition, simply do not call cursor.continue at that point.

Third, is that even if decide to load all objects from the store first, it would be far better to use a for loop than exploit `some`. By exploit I mean use the function in a way other than it was intended. I bet that if you revert to using a for loop with a break statement, the code will be clearer and therefore it will be simpler to understand why the loop does not break when you expect it to do so.

Fourth, is that I would take the time to append results of an indexedDB query to an intermediate data structure, like an array, rather than immediately interacting with the DOM. It will separate things more, and you will find the code simpler to debug.

Fifth is that you should be very careful when mixing async calls together with indexedDB. indexedDB is known to have problems when you interleave calls to other promises.

Comment: thanks for this, especially point four - it went nuts when I tried interleaving the calls, so have ended up putting the `pdb.allDocs` call outside the `getRoomsInRoute() ` function altogether. Let's see if that works :)